# JavaScript Self Invoking Function on addEventListener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, self-invoking-function

I'm not being able to make a function of an Event Listener self invoke and the listener to work.

The following code executes the function, but the Event Listener don't work:

```
window.addEventListener("resize", (function () {
document.getElementById("divMenu").innerHTML = document.getElementById("divTop").offsetWidth
})())
```

The function will set a needed (dynamic since the beginning) CSS style essential to the website formatting. The "resize" function MUST be executed at load.
Is it possible to make this, or should i create a separate Self Invoking Function and call it on the Event Listener?

Comment: What is purpose of using self invoking function ?

Comment: the function will set a needed (dynamic since the beginning) CSS style essential to the website formatting. The "resize" function MUST be executed at load.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you immediately invoke the function, it's return value is put in it's place (`window.addEventListener('resize', undefined)`). Instead, define your function outside of the event listener then add it and call it.

```
function onResize() {
  document.getElementById('divMenu').innerHTML = document.getElementById("divTop").offsetWidth;
}
window.addEventListener('resize', onResize);
onResize();
```

Technically, you could make this work using a self-invoking function but it's a bit screwy and I wouldn't suggest it.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', (function onResize() {
  document.getElementById('divMenu').innerHTML = document.getElementById("divTop").offsetWidth;
  // Works because it returns a function
  return onResize;
})());
```

Comment: Ah, good call - makes sense why you want to run the function at the same time as assigning it now.

Comment: So Mike, you're saying you can't have Self Invoking Functions on Event Listeners? James: I've edited my question to include that information.

Comment: @Dillinger You can if the self-invoking function returns another function or itself. Remember: a function always returns a value and that value will effectively "replace" the function when passed as an argument.

Comment: So, onResize() auto executes once, and replaces itself by itself as the function of the event listener, correct? I was just thinking why returning itself don't make an infinite loop, or the return don't go as part of the function?

Comment: @Dillinger It doesn't literally replace itself. Imagine you had a function called `getFour` that returns `4`. If you call something like `add(getFour(), 4)` then it's the same thing as writing `add(4, 4)`, right? So since you're executing the function immediately, it's the same as if you had declared it somewhere else then did `window.addEventListener('resize', onResize())`. You're putting the return value there. So you need to return a function if you want it to immediately invoke itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your IIF returns undefined, but eventlistener must be a function, or link to function. Add return to your IIF or pass function:

Anonymous function:

```
 window.addEventListener("resize", function () {
    document.getElementById("divMenu").innerHTML = document.getElementById("divTop").offsetWidth
 }))
```

IIF, that returns a function

```
 window.addEventListener("resize", (function () {
 return function(){
    document.getElementById("divMenu").innerHTML = document.getElementById("divTop").offsetWidth
 }
 })())
```

Edited (invoke assignment on startup):

```
window.addEventListener("resize", (function () {
  function set_innerHtml(){
    document.getElementById("divMenu").innerHTML = document.getElementById("divTop").offsetWidth
  }
  set_innerHtml();
  return set_innerHtml;
})())
```

Comment: Your answer seems what i need but it's not working at startup, put an alert inside the return function you will see only pops-up on resize